# Linear to sRGB conversion

Tags: python, srgb

I'm trying to convert values from to srgb/linear.
I have this equation which works great, but I can't get it back after wards:

```
if(C <= 0.0404482362771082):
    lin = C/12.92
else:
    lin = pow(((C+0.055)/1.055), 2.4)
```

But getting it back using this does not work:

```
if(C <= 0.00313066844250063):
    lin = C*12.92
else:
    lin = pow((1.055*C),(1/2.4))-0.055
```

So I figured I could create some kind of table and get Python to calculate the equation but I'm not sure... How can I do it? I have these values with sRGB > Linear conversion I'd like to somehow use that as guide to get my liner > sRGB conversion... Or other way around I keep getting lost here...

```
0.05 ---- 0.00393593950409
0.06 ---- 0.00489631008162
0.07 ---- 0.00598105957262
0.08 ---- 0.00719440929108
0.09 ---- 0.00854038211212
0.1 ---- 0.0100228255749
0.11 ---- 0.0116454309058
0.12 ---- 0.0134117488977
0.13 ---- 0.0153252033206
0.14 ---- 0.0173891023685
0.15 ---- 0.0196066485162
0.16 ---- 0.0219809470799
0.17 ---- 0.0245150137035
0.18 ---- 0.0272117809514
0.19 ---- 0.0300741041466
0.2 ---- 0.0331047665709
0.21 ---- 0.0363064841182
0.22 ---- 0.0396819094785
0.23 ---- 0.0432336359153
0.24 ---- 0.0469642006891
0.25 ---- 0.0508760881716
0.26 ---- 0.0549717326876
0.27 ---- 0.0592535211173
0.28 ---- 0.0637237952849
0.29 ---- 0.0683848541582
0.3 ---- 0.0732389558784
0.31 ---- 0.0782883196387
0.32 ---- 0.0835351274258
0.33 ---- 0.0889815256384
0.34 ---- 0.0946296265946
0.35 ---- 0.100481509938
0.36 ---- 0.106539223951
0.37 ---- 0.112804786787
0.38 ---- 0.119280187622
0.39 ---- 0.125967387741
0.4 ---- 0.132868321554
0.41 ---- 0.139984897558
0.42 ---- 0.147318999244
0.43 ---- 0.15487248595
0.44 ---- 0.162647193668
0.45 ---- 0.170644935816
0.46 ---- 0.178867503956
0.47 ---- 0.187316668488
0.48 ---- 0.195994179301
0.49 ---- 0.204901766398
0.5 ---- 0.214041140482
0.51 ---- 0.223413993525
0.52 ---- 0.233021999301
0.53 ---- 0.242866813904
0.54 ---- 0.252950076231
0.55 ---- 0.263273408456
0.56 ---- 0.273838416473
0.57 ---- 0.284646690328
0.58 ---- 0.295699804626
0.59 ---- 0.306999318928
0.6 ---- 0.318546778125
0.61 ---- 0.330343712804
0.62 ---- 0.342391639593
0.63 ---- 0.354692061494
0.64 ---- 0.36724646821
0.65 ---- 0.38005633645
0.66 ---- 0.393123130227
0.67 ---- 0.406448301147
0.68 ---- 0.420033288684
0.69 ---- 0.433879520449
0.7 ---- 0.447988412442
0.71 ---- 0.462361369307
0.72 ---- 0.476999784567
0.73 ---- 0.491905040857
0.74 ---- 0.507078510149
0.75 ---- 0.522521553968
0.76 ---- 0.538235523601
0.77 ---- 0.554221760299
0.78 ---- 0.570481595475
0.79 ---- 0.587016350894
0.8 ---- 0.603827338855
0.81 ---- 0.620915862374
0.82 ---- 0.638283215352
0.83 ---- 0.655930682747
0.84 ---- 0.673859540734
0.85 ---- 0.692071056865
0.86 ---- 0.710566490224
0.87 ---- 0.729347091573
0.88 ---- 0.748414103499
0.89 ---- 0.767768760555
0.9 ---- 0.787412289396
0.91 ---- 0.807345908913
0.92 ---- 0.827570830363
0.93 ---- 0.848088257495
0.94 ---- 0.868899386673
0.95 ---- 0.890005406994
0.96 ---- 0.911407500406
0.97 ---- 0.933106841824
0.98 ---- 0.955104599234
0.99 ---- 0.977401933806
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your inversion looks wrong. I have tried-and-true code that look like this:

```
if (varR > 0.0031308) {
    varR = 1.055 * (pow(varR, (1.0 / 2.4))) - 0.055;
} else {
    varR = 12.92 * varR;
}
```

I.e. the multiplication by 1.055 has to be outside of the power function.

Comment: Thanks, but I just compared a formula ;)